# How to display each day of a month on a separate line using tr, sed and cal

Tags: sed, tr, cal

How to use commands, `cal`, `sed` and `tr` and the pipe to display the numerical days (e.g., 1, 2, 3, etc.) of a month, with each day on a separate line

I've tried:

```
cal 12 2015| sed '3,7p' | tr -cs "[:alpha:]" "[\n*]"
```

and go this output:

```
December
S
M
Tu
W
Th
F
S
```

Comment: With homework questions, you need to show us what you have tried...

Answer (score 4):

You came close.

1. You need to suppress `sed`'s output before selectively printing lines:

   ```
   $ cal 12 2015 | sed -n '3,7p'                             
          1  2  3  4  5  
    6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
   13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
   20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
   27 28 29 30 31
   ```

   Your `sed` might not have `-n`. In which case, use `d` to delete all lines except the ones you want.
2. Your `tr` command replaces everything except alpahabets - and that includes digits. Just replace spaces:

   ```
   $ cal 12 2015 | sed -n '3,7p' | tr -s ' ' '\n'                

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
   11
   12
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The range of lines in the `sed` command by [@muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) caught my eye. You can do this relying less upon the format of `cal`:

```
cal 12 2015 | sed '/[[:alpha:]]/d' | tr ' ' '\n' |sed -e '/^$/d'
```

POSIX does not specify the format for [`cal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cal.html), so the length of the header could vary by implementation.